# A question about the names of the non-abelian groups of order $p^3$.

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, terminology, p-groups

It is well known that given an odd prime $p$, there exist two finite non-abelian groups of order $p^3$: A group with exponent $p$ and a group with exponent $p^2$. The group with exponent $p$ is known as **Heisenberg group modulo $p$** and is usually denoted by $H_3(\mathbb Z/(p))$. Does the group with exponent $p^2$ has a special name? If not, does it have a special notation? Thanks.

Comment: In group theory the Heisenberg group is usually labelled $p^{1+2}_+$ (because of the sign of the form on $G/Z(G)$). The other group is denoted $p^{1+2}_-$, Its name is 'p to the one plus two minus'.

Comment: Thanks David. To be honest, I have never encountered this notation. Do you know any other known notation ?

Comment: @DavidA.Craven I am familiar this notation for $p=2$, but not for odd $p$. For odd $p$, the form is symplectic and is the the same (or equivalent) for both isomorphism classes of groups. The difference between the two groups lies in their exponenets.

Comment: @DerekHolt You are right, for odd primes it's the exponent that labels the + and -. Here is one example that uses this notation: https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/~matyd/GroupNames/extraspecial.html

Comment: @boaz I know of no other notation that is used in more than one place. The other group is sometimes called the modular $p$-group, because it's part of an infinite series of groups with a cyclic subgroups of index $p$, but I think that notation is only in Gorenstein's book.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven Yes and (as I already knew and had forgotten) Magma uses that notation, in the sense that, in the function $\mathtt{ExtraSpecialGroup}$,  you can set the $\mathtt{Type}$ to be "+" or "-".

Comment: You could say $p_{-}^{1+2}$ is the "extraspecial group of minus type of order $p^3$".

Answer (score 0):

It may be interesting to mention that the other group $G_p$ of order $p^3$ is the *unique Sylow $p$-subgroup of the affine group ${\rm Aff}(\Bbb Z/p^2)$*, i.e., the kernel of the homomorphism
$$
{\rm Aff}(\Bbb Z/p^2) \rightarrow (\Bbb Z/p^2)^{\times}
$$
given by $\begin{pmatrix} a & b \cr 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \mapsto a^p$.

But of course the name "unique $p$-Sylow subgroup of an affine group" is too long.

For a similar discussion concerning the notation here see

[Notations for groups of order $p^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180250/notations-for-groups-of-order-p3)